# How to setup a password for PostgreSQL in postgreapp?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, passwords, postgresql-12

I am using postgresapp for the PostgreSQL and without password I was able to connect to the database and perform operations. I am curious to learn about the password. Also I use Postico as Interface. Open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

The default for `Postgres.app` is to have no password and set `trust`-level authentication in `pg_hba.conf`.  To change this, you need to do the following:

- Alter the IP address and mask for `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32             trust` as needed in `pg_hba.conf`, and change authentication method from `trust` to `password` or `md5` (or whatever your requirements are)
- Set the password for the desired user(s) with `ALTER USER <username> WITH PASSWORD '<password>';`
- Reload the conf with `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`

Note your `pg_hba.conf` file is usually located in `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-12` -- the sure-fire way to know is by querying `SHOW data_directory` in your `psql` prompt

Answer (score -2):

Postgres.app is a great way to get Postgres running on macOS in a few minutes. It ships with a default user name and password, and they you're on your own. Postgres.app is a nicely compiled version of Postgres that you can run by double-clicking, you'll need other tools (and knowledge) to take advantage of Postgres. As you'll have noticed, the UI for Postgres.app is pretty much a few buttons to configure a server, and to give you shortcuts to the logs, configuration files, and data.

If you want to use psql (as mentioned), or any of the other command line tools, they're embedded in the application's package. Right-click, open the package, open Contents, open Versions, open the version you use, and look in bin.

If you want a GUI tool, there are many options. Since you say Postgres.app, I'll assume macOS. You've found Postico, SQLPro for Postgres is good, TablePlus is also good. Those tools have fairly uncluttered UIs. If you want or need more features, pgAdmin has a whole lot to offer, and it's free. I end up using Navicat a lot, even though it has a UI that screams "Look Ma! I wrote it in Java!" It gets a lot done. I'd say that day-to-day on macOS, I use SQLPro most. But, really, it's largely a matter of taste. psql is quite powerful, and you'll find no short of help for that.